# Finding the real part of the logarithmic derivative of a real polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

If $P(z)=-z^nP(1/z)$ is a  polynomial with real coefficients, then   I think 
$$\Re\left(\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}\right)=\frac{n}{2} $$ on $|z|=1$ and $P(z)\neq 0.$  I am trying to establish it by obtaining $\left(\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}\right)-\frac{n}{2} $ as  purely imaginary value. Whether my approach is achievable?  If $P(z)=-z^nP(1/z)$ is not real what should be the conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithmic derivative of the identity $P(z)=-z^nP(1/z)$ gives
$$
\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)} = \frac nz - \frac{P'(\frac 1z)}{P(\frac 1z)} \frac{1}{z^2} 
\implies \frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)} = n - \frac{P'(\frac 1z)}{P(\frac 1z)} \frac{1}{z} \, .
$$

If  $|z|=1$ then
$
 P(\frac 1z) = P(\overline z) = \overline{P(z)}
$
because $P$ has real coefficients, and therefore
$$
\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)} = n - \frac{ \overline{P'(z)}}{\overline{P(z)}} \overline z \, .
$$
Now take the real parts
$$
\Re\left(\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}\right) = n - \Re\left(\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}\right) 
$$
and the conclusion follows.